# TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling equivelent for Newtonsoft.Json 8

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm working on modding a Rust(the game) dedicated server, which comes with Newtonsoft.Json version 8.0.0.0. It would help me out a quite a bit if anyone knows what the 8.0.0.0 equivelent to this is.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple
});
```

The best answer I can find from newtonsoft's documentation is...

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
     TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
     TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
});
```

but it doesn't have the desired effect, the assembly version number is still there. Does anyone know how to do this?

The Json string that I'm getting

```
"$type": "Oxide.Ext.GameStateMachine.StateMachine, plugins_24206636",
  "current_state": {
    "$type": "Oxide.Ext.GunGame.GunGameState, plugins_24206636",
    "player_stats": {
      "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.UInt64, mscorlib],[Oxide.Ext.GunGame.GunGamePlayerStats, plugins_24206636]], mscorlib"
    },
```

The exception.Message that I'm getting when I attempt to deserialize with the same JsonSerializerSettings...

https://i.gyazo.com/3d7a218cc0d4a3a223723ad578973ebd.png

Comment: Sample input? expected output?

Comment: The JSON string you show already doesn't include assembly version information.  If it did it the `$type` properties would look like `"$type": "Oxide.Ext.GunGame.StateMachine, plugins_24206636, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",`  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/biTCOm) showing the JSON with simple and full assembly names, in an old version of Json.NET.  So the JSON string you're getting is in fact the one you want.

Comment: Do you know what the "plugins_24206636" refers to and how I get rid of it? The number changes everytime I modify the plugin code which largely defeats the point.

Comment: It's the assembly **name** not the assembly version; see the docs for [`Type.GetType(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) for details on the type string format.  It looks like you are making some sort of a plugin and your host app is generating a new run-time assembly name every time you run.  Usually the assembly name is stable even when the version changes.

Comment: To deal with that you might start with [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666511/how-to-create-a-serializationbinder-for-the-binary-formatter-that-handles-the-mo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19666511).  (older versions of Json.NET use the same `SerializationBinder` as `BinaryFormatter`.)

Comment: you're right, oxide does seem to do compile the plugin with a different assembly name each time, i've looked into that SerializationBinder class and it looks like its the best route forward. thank you!