# Update field values prior to json deserialization, based on property name and value [Newtonsoft / JSON.Net]

Tags: json, json.net

I have the below sample JSON:

```
﻿[
  {
    "$type": "TestProject.Classes.TestClass, TestProject",
    "Name": "TestCommand",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Age": 0,
        "Eta": 8,
        "Gender": "Ragel"
      },
      {
        "Age": 0,
        "Eta": 20,
        "Gender": "Mara"
      }
    ],
    "School": {
      "Title": "School for Life"
    }
  }
]
```

This is deserialized from a data source (message in the message queue). There are some types which have changed in the codebase, and I would like to still be able to map the old types to the new ones.

For the example, let's imagine the type `TestClass` no longer exists, but now is `TestClassNew`.  I have mappings stored to be able to map from the old to the new type. I am trying to alter the `$type` value prior to the object being deserialised, such that its string value is changed from `TestProject.Classes.TestClass, TestProject` to `TestProject.Classes.TestClassNew, TestProject`.

I was trying using a JsonConvertor, but not sure if that is the right way - haven't managed to do it. Any help on how this can be done would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using a version of Json.NET before 10.0, take a look at [How to create a SerializationBinder for the Binary Formatter that handles the moving of types from one assembly and namespace to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19666511).  If you are using a later version then Json.NET now uses [`ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder.htm) but the idea is the same, see [Custom SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm).

Comment: It's a good idea to have a custom serialization binder that sanitizes incoming types anyway for security reasons, see [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39614563).

Comment: Or wait - do you not know the new `"$type"` based on the old `"$type"` and need to look at the actual properties present?  Your question title says *based on property name and value* but your question text doesn't really reflect this.