# Serialization of objects through network

Tags: c#, json, web-services, serialization, serializable

I read articles about the benefits of sending serialized objects through network. Performance and size cost.

Some explained about DataContract and using JSON or XML serialization.

But I can't find articles about what happens if I don't use these attributes and I return a object assuming that my object's properties and states are of primitive types. Obviously when I use a serializer like DataContractJsonSerializer and its WriteObject method concretely, it's gonna throw an exception.

***What would happen if I return for example in a web service method, an object of Employee type which has the attribute 'Serializable'. I mean what would .net would treat this result.***

```
[WebMethod]
public Employee SendEmployeeData()
{
}
```

The object would be sent through network as binary stream or what?

Is it required to serialize an object to send it throught network?

I also read that DataContractSerializer would interpret the Serializable attribute.

[difference between DataContract attribute and Serializable attribute in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545439/difference-between-datacontract-attribute-and-serializable-attribute-in-net)

Comment: A quick note: use Json.NET, rather than DataContractSerializer. The performance is indisputably better, and the attribute annotation is cleaner IMO.  Even Microsoft are using Json.NET in WebAPI 2.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. It's not the first time that I heard that and I'm starting to read and explore about it.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean what would .net would treat this result.

That would intend entirely on the framework / frameworks you are using. WCF will work differently to ASMX, which will work differently to MVC, which will ... blah blah blah.

> The object would be send through network as binary stream or what?

Yes; TCP streams are streams

> Is it required to serialize an object to send it throught network?

Yes; you can only send a series of bytes through a data; the process of converting an object to a series of bytes is called serialization.

> I also read that DataContractSerializer would interpret the Serializable attribute.

Well... sort of... that isn't a great usage, though, and is akin to using `BinaryFormatter` (it might use `NetDataContractSerializer`, but this has most of the same problems) - basically: *don't do that*. If you are using an API that is intended to exchange data-contracts, *use a data-contract*. There is no "best" approach here; it all comes down to what you are trying to do and what your priorities are. JSON and XML have interoperability advantages over `BinaryFormatter` et al, but there are other options too with the same benefits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to your TCP streams phrase. Does .Net require that my objects have the Serializable attribute or not?

Comment: @MaximusDecimus pretty much the only thing that cares about `[Serializable]` is `BinaryFormatter`, which you shouldn't be using anyway; the main thing that uses `BinaryFormatter` *without you knowing* is *remoting*, which you shouldn't be using anyway. So if you aren't using things that require `[Serializable]`, no you don't need to add `[Serializable]`

Comment: I'll add to @MarcGravell's comment, that I think it would be advisable to do a little more research on TCP streams (and other transport mechanisms), and ask another question specifically related to that topic.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, DataContractSerializer is pretty explicit about requiring attribute annotations on all properties and objects that need to be serialized. I might be wrong about this though: it's been a while since I've used it.

They will *definitely not* be automagically serialized using a BinaryFormatter. The Serializable attribute is just a marker to *tell* a BinaryFormatter to serialize an object.

Json.NET (which I've referenced in my comment) will use reflection to build a serialized structure of a given object - even `dynamic` ones. The following code will construct a dynamic object and convert it to a JSON string, using JSON.net:

```
//build request
var dynamicObject = new {
    message = "Hello World",
    number = 32,
    date = DateTime.Now
};

//convert to JSON string
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamicObject);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: If you don't annotate *at all*, IIRC it falls back to behaviour much like `BinaryFormatter` - which is *not* to be recommended

Comment: @MarcGravell - Yes, thanks for clarifying this. As you've said in your answer, a well-defined contract is definitely the way to go.